# Android Wear GridViewPager Gesture

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have GridViewPager with 2 rows and 3 columns. As its default behavior If u swipe down on any page it will navigate to first page of next row. But i want to override that behaviorand stop Swipe Down on first row second and third columns.

I have tried putting 2 row one column GridViewPager and putting a ViewPager for first cell as well as using 1 row 3 column GridViewPager with putting Another 1 column 2 row GridViewPager in first cell. Both has similar scrolling problems.Bellow code is the custom GridViewPager I used to change scrolling behavior.

GridViewPager should be able swipe only as following picture.[Swipe Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpeR5.png)

```
public class GridViewPagerCustom extends GridViewPager {
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private int px = 0;
    private int py = 0;

    public int getPy() {
        return py;
    }

    public void setPy(int py) {
        this.py = py;
    }

    public int getPx() {
        return selectedPage;
    }

    public void setPx(int px) {
        this.px = px;
    }

    public GridViewPagerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction
    class YScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return (getPx() == 0 && getPy() == 0) ? Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX) : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control that by overriding `canScrollVertically(int direction)`; I haven't tried that but sounds like the right place. That said, please be careful about changing that behavior since it will then be different from other apps that use this component and users of your app may get confused assuming that there are no other rows, etc.